# Error receiving mail with python 3 "sequence item 0: expected str instance, bytes found"

Tags: python, python-3.x, email

I'm trying to receive emails on python with poplib, when I run the code I keep getting the following output `sequence item 0: expected str instance, bytes found`. Here is the whole code, if anyone knows a much simpler way of printing the receiving mail, I would appreciate if you could comment it. I would also like to be able to print only the emails of an determinate email. Thankyou.

```
import poplib
from email import parser
pop_conn = poplib.POP3_SSL('pop.gmail.com')
pop_conn.user('mail@gmail.com')
pop_conn.pass_('password')

messages = [pop_conn.retr(i) for i in range(1, len(pop_conn.list()[1]) + 1)]
# Concat message pieces:
messages = ["\n".join(mssg[1]) for mssg in messages]
#Parse message intom an email object:
messages = [parser.Parser().parsestr(mssg) for mssg in messages]
print(message.keys())
for message in messages:
    print(message['subject'])
    print(message.get_payload())
pop_conn.quit()
```

Comment: Please try to add the whole error all the way to where it says Traceback. It helps greatly when trying to know what's wrong with the code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises in your line

`messages = ["\n".join(mssg[1]) for mssg in messages]`

Here you are trying to join `"\n"` which is a string, with `mssg[1]` which is technically a list, and it contains bytes strings. To make that specific line work, you can do `messages = [b"\n".join(mssg[1]) for mssg in messages]` (notice the b) to make it work. However you will again run into problems when calling `parsestr()` of `Parser`, because what you are parsing to it is again `mssg[1]`, which is not a string. Look into the documentation of `email.Parser` it should have a function which accepts bytes instead of strings as input.

Also I personally would use IMAP instead of POP.